# InApp purchase payment done or not

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase, storekit

I wanna find out whether the payment has been made by the apple or not??

Is it possible to knw???

Since we get the same receipt for the restore transaction and payment transaction, is it possible to knw that payment is made???

Answer (score 1):

Yes - In app purchase has been available for a while now. You can see the Apple API for it here, which should answer all the questions you have. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: There is nothing written about the payment received by the apple.

Comment: Could you try and rephrase please? I'll try to help out but I don't really understand what you mean.

Comment: Apple says - For the RestoreTransactionRequest, apple sends the same response receipt as it sends for the PurchaseRequest.

But, how do we knw that wether the apple has got its payment or not??